# Export only list_display columns with verbose_names?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-import-export

Hello I am newbie for django so I have basic question.
In my admin class I added ExportMixin and I want to save excel file with my list_display columns and verbose names.

Not id column or let's say I have status it says keep going or not doing but I show 0-1 under the status.

I am still looking for the answer please help me :)

MyCode:

```
@admin.register(Ico)
class IcoAdmin(ExportMixin, BaseAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'account', 'pair', 'amount', 'ico_situation', 'expire_date', 'price',
        'token_amount', 'reference_user', 'get_reference_user_income')
    list_filter = ('account', 'account__is_bot')
    search_fields = ('account_id', 'wallet_id', 'ico_situation')

    raw_id_fields = ('account', 'pair', 'wallet', 'reference_user')
```

My Excel table :

| id | account | wallet | pair | amount | token_amount | final_token_amount | expire_date | status | ico_situation | price | reference_code | reference_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 152 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 400 | 0 | 2022-03-17 | 1 | 1 | 0,25 |  |  |
| 151 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 2021-11-17 | 1 | 0 | 0,5 |  |  |
| 150 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 2021-11-17 | 1 | 0 | 0,5 |  | 2 |
| 149 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 2021-11-17 | 1 | 0 | 0,5 |  |  |
| 148 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 2021-11-17 | 1 | 0 | 0,5 |  | 2 |
| 147 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 2021-11-17 | 1 | 0 | 0,5 |  |  |
| 146 | 111 | 789 | 12 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 2021-11-17 | 1 | 0 | 0,5 |  | 2 |

Table I want:
(https://ibb.co/8YpQ0S1)

Thanks for the helps :)

Comment: you need to declare a [resource](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting) for your export.  You can run the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) to see what to do.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty thanks I clone example app but I saw your excel file contains all your model filed. I want my excel file just my admin page list_display fields ? Is it possible to make ? Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a [Resource](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#creating-import-export-resource) on the Admin class you can control which fields appear in the export.  You list the fields you want to export in the `fields` Meta attribute.

```py
class IcoResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Ico
        fields = (
            'account', 'pair', 'amount', 'ico_situation', 'expire_date', 'price',
            'token_amount', 'reference_user', 'get_reference_user_income'
        )
        
        
@admin.register(Ico)
class IcoAdmin(ExportMixin, BaseAdmin):
    resource_class = IcoResource

    # ... your other fields here
```

You can control how the fields are exported by using [widgets](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html)

I hope I have understood your issue correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found my solution.

codes here:
--the example app's admin page

```
 class BookResource(ModelResource):
    published = Field(attribute='published', column_name='Basim Tarihi')
    yazaradi = Field(attribute='author__name', column_name='Yazar Adi')
    # ico_situation = Field(attribute='ico_situation', column_name='Ico Durumu')
    imported = Field(attribute='imported', column_name='Onemli MI')
    ico_situation = Field(attribute='ico_situation')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        widgets = {
            'published': {'format': '%d.%m.%Y'},
        }

        fields = ('yazaradi', 'price', 'author_email', 'categories', 'published', 'imported', 'ico_situation')
        export_order = ('yazaradi', 'price', 'author_email', 'categories', 'published', 'imported', 'ico_situation')

    def for_delete(self, row, instance):
        return self.fields['name'].clean(row) == ''


class BookAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'author', 'added')
    list_filter = ['categories', 'author']
    resource_class = BookResource
```

you can rename excel colums under the ModelResource class